# Delete all rows that don't contain the max value in group

Tags: sql, max, sql-delete

I have a twist to this popular question and accepted answer:  [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

I have a table structured similarly but instead of SELECTing the rows with the highest datatime I'd like to DELETE all the rows within each ID grouping that don't contain the max datetime.  The query should make the table smaller in terms of rows.

I've tried using the accepted answer's select query in a WHERE NOT EXISTS sub query but I get the error  "You can't specify target table ... for update in From clause"

How would you alter this to DELETE the rows that don't meet the SELECT requirement here:

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM topten tt
INNER JOIN
    (
     SELECT home, MAX(datetime) AS MaxDateTime
     FROM topten
     GROUP BY home
    ) groupedtt ON tt.home = groupedtt.home AND tt.datetime = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

With ID being the primary key of your table

```
;with
GetResults
AS
(
    SELECT tt.*
    FROM topten tt
    INNER JOIN
        (
         SELECT home, MAX(datetime) AS MaxDateTime
         FROM topten
         GROUP BY home
        ) groupedtt ON tt.home = groupedtt.home AND tt.datetime = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
)
    DELETE GetResults
    FROM topten tt LEFT JOIN GetResults ON tt.ID = GetResults.ID
    WHERE GetResults.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Please forgive my SQL ignorance, but is  `;with GetResults` part of the SQL statement?  If it means anything, I'd like to be able to enter this SQL into the Run Query dialogue in phpMyAdmin to cleanup a large table.

Comment: `;with`  means you are using a Common Table Expression (you can check online for SQL CTE). `GetResults` is just a name that I've given it but you can change it with anything you want. On a side note, always remember to back up your DB before any update/delete statements you run.

Answer (score 0):

with `id` being the pk of `topten`:

```
    delete
      from topten tt1
     where tt1.id NOT IN (
                 SELECT tt2.id
                   FROM topten tt2
             INNER JOIN (
                          SELECT home, MAX(datetime) AS MaxDateTime
                          FROM topten tt3
                          GROUP BY home
                        ) groupedtt ON tt2.home = groupedtt.home AND tt2.datetime = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
           )
         ;
```

Comment: Hey thanks but I get an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tt1 where tt1.id NOT IN ( SELECT tt2.id ' at line 2